# Unity can't recognize class and namespace, how can I fix it?

Tags: unity, c#

I just updated Unity to 5.4 today, though as I saw, this problem was present in previous versions too.

So the error message is :

> The type or namespace name 'FirstPersonController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This happens when I try to reference the FPSController prefab's FirstPersonController.cs (obviously I'm talking about the one from StandardAssets/Characters).

Yes, I did try including

```
using *UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson*
```

in my script, but no, it did not work. Doesn't even recognize is as a valid namespace.

The same happens when I try the other way: when I try referencing my script inside the FirstPersonController.cs. It just doesn't recognize it as valid.

Anybody has any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is the file name the same name as the class?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, weeks later, now it's working. I have no idea how or why, but now it recognizes the UnityStandardAssets namespace and the others as well. So now I can just use FirstPersonController and a static variable I made inside it and modify it so it works just like I wanted. Weird though

Answer (score 2):

I had an identical issue with the `AeroplaneController` script.

While I do not acknowledge it as the absolute solution, I solved the issue by actually moving the script to my local scripts folder.

The problem appears to be in having native access to scripts across a folder hierarchy. If script A is in a different parent folder to script B, neither will have the ability to immediately reference each other.

Ofcourse, this added some other problems. In my case, `AeroplaneController` referenced one or two scripts (or *was* referenced *by*, I honestly can not remember for sure), and moving it outside of the folder structure removed the ability to see the other scripts / `AeroplaneController` from the other scripts. I would have either moved the important scripts, as well, or removed the reference to `AeroplaneController` in the unimportant scripts simply to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a conflict between the versions of unity the project is referencing.

Are you using VS to edit your scripts? If so, expand the `references` node in the solution explorer and see if you have any missing/broken references.